# Accessing Data From Another Application

Tags: c++

I currently have a server (called worldserver) that, when it starts, pulls data from multiple sources (mainly database), and every 5 minutes saves the modified data back into the database.
Since it is still in development, I am wondering - can I somehow load all the data the worldserver needs to load when it starts into a separate background application, and have the main server load data from there?

Here's my logic:
Having two different applications, one of them that stores data only (background application), and another that pulls data from there and updates the database every 5 minutes (worldserver).

I want to kill the data read between worldserver and the database, and make it read data from the background application (which realistically never needs to crash as all it does is store data and gather dust on the machine's RAM).

The reason I am thinking about it is because RAM is the fastest memory storage on a PC, and can optimize the server loading time significantly.

Is such a thing possible? If that IS in fact possible, is it recommended? I seek maximum optimization and data loss prevention as much as possible.

I tried searching online how to make this thing possible but encountered a Stackoverflow thread that says you cannot read data from multiple processes as the OS system restricts it.

Comment: you certainly can get data from other processes via mechanisms such as COM, but in this case i think one server will do. anything else is just a complication.

Comment: The reason I am even thinking about this is this thread here, from a game called Star Citizen.
They made a new tech called "Entity Streaming", you can read about it here: https://robertsspaceindustries.com/comm-link/transmission/18696-Letter-From-The-Chairman

Comment: i am not sure that star citizen is something you should be seeking to emulate

Comment: Only a certain aspect of it, since on paper it seems very smart and useful. Just a theory at the moment.

Comment: How much data do use during testing? To me inter process communication sounds like something that could easily result in errors. Simply sending the server a message that results in the server reinitializing itself by e.g. reloading the db from a specific file from the harddrive seems like a much simpler, easier to implement approach. This feature can be deactivated later or be made only available, if the server program is executed with specific parameters later...

Comment: Can reach a few gigabytes in memory as it supports multiple maps and consecutive players @fabian

Comment: @fabian i am sure that the other users of the server will be entirely happy with your client sending it messages saying "reboot" /s

Comment: @Insta a  few gigs is nothing these days on a server-class machine

Comment: Could be, but I am looking for something scalable and optimized since the beginning. Besides, this is a single instance of the server.
You mentioned COM, I'll check this out. But in reality, you think this is simply overcomplicated and will not benefit me?

Comment: i think it over-complicated and you can probably better do it with one app. but i don't really have enough info to say for sure

Comment: @Instadev You could allocate a block of shared memory that is shared between the two processes, as long as they are running on the same machine.  But, this seems a little overkill when your main server could just use an in-memory database instead, and flush it to the real database periodically. No need for a separate data-only process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau problem is in case the server crashes, then all the data is lost and I am back to loading from SQL or files and such. Unless there's a way to keep the in-memory database alive despite application termination / crash handling?